# jquery wrap an iframe in div

Tags: jquery, iframe

How would I make jquery wrap an iframe in a div e.g if using a vimeo embed iframe, on load jquery wraps it in a div class:

```
<div class="iframe"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23358638?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use jQuery [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function :

```
$("iframe").wrap("<div class='iframe'/>");
```